# Scalar subquery produced more than one element exception when aggregating multiple unnest elements

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following query for the BigQuery instance:

```
CREATE TABLE my_dataset.PRODUCT AS (
  SELECT "1,2,3" AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_IDS UNION ALL
  SELECT "2,3" AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_IDS UNION ALL
  SELECT "1" AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_IDS
);

CREATE TABLE my_dataset.DESCRIPTION AS (
    SELECT "1" AS DESCRIPTION_ID, "VALUE1" AS DESCRIPTION_VALUE UNION ALL
    SELECT "2" AS DESCRIPTION_ID, "VALUE2" AS DESCRIPTION_VALUE UNION ALL
    SELECT "3" AS DESCRIPTION_ID, "VALUE3" AS DESCRIPTION_VALUE
);

SELECT

  FORMAT('%T', ARRAY_AGG(ELEMENT)) AS desc_ids,
  FORMAT('%T', ARRAY_AGG((SELECT DESCRIPTION_VALUE FROM my_dataset.DESCRIPTION WHERE DESCRIPTION_ID = ELEMENT))) AS desc_values,

FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT 
    SPLIT(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_IDS, ',') as arr 
  FROM my_dataset.PRODUCT 
  limit 1
)) AS ELEMENT
```

It executes fine but only when I have limit 1 specified, otherwise I receive an exception:

`Scalar subquery produced more than one element`

How should I update my query to receive not only one resulting row but all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select 
  format('%T', array_agg(ELEMENT)) as desc_ids, 
  format('%T', array_agg(DESCRIPTION_VALUE)) as desc_values
from PRODUCT t, unnest(split(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_IDS)) as ELEMENT 
left join DESCRIPTION 
on ELEMENT = DESCRIPTION_ID
group by format('%T',t)
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]